# Are there any MongoDB ORM's in PHP similar to mongoid?

Tags: php, orm, mongodb, mongoid

I like mongoid mapper in ruby, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Libraries,+Frameworks,+and+Tools lists down many ORM/mappers in php for mongoDB but none looks as good as mongoid(at least at first glance).

is there a MongoDB ORM in PHP similar to mongoid? that provides facility like embedding, refernces etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think that Doctrine is close to what you're looking for. But recognize that PHP and Ruby tend to have different syntaxes. So things like embedding and referencing will also look a little different.

Also recognize that while Mongoid (and many others) have some great features regarding embedding/reference they are do carry some risks. It's really easy to create structures that are difficult to query or difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

They are all there... Personally I like [Mongodloid](http://code.google.com/p/mongodloid/).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/parf/Mongo-PHP-ORM